# yFinance financials (balance sheet, cashflow, etc.) return as an empty dataframe - how do I get it to return information?

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm trying to use yfinance to get company financial details - whenever I call a function to get financials for a ticker (such as income_stmt, balance_sheet, cashflow, etc.) an empty dataframe is returned. I've tried following steps here from a few years ago (https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/191) but the base.py file seems to have changed, it doesn't have the code referenced here anymore. Other functions seem to work fine (actions, history, etc.). Why can't I get the financials to be returned?

Example:

```
import yfinance as yf 
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT") 
msft.get_balance_sheet()
```

This just returns an empty dataframe

```
     Open   High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date
```

This works just fine though:

```
msft.history()

    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Dividends   Stock Splits
Date                            
2023-11-15  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.75    0
2023-11-16  370.959991  376.350006  370.179993  376.170013  27182300.0  0.00    0
2023-11-17  373.609985  374.369995  367.000000  369.850006  40157000.0  0.00    0
2023-11-20  371.220001  378.869995  371.000000  377.440002  52465100.0  0.00    0
```

I have tried looking at the base.py file in the yfinance repo per these tips, but the file seems to have changed: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/191